# Need help understanding JS code produced by TypeScript namespaces

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was going through the basics of TypeScript where I came across something called `namespaces`. This is the typescript code:

```
namespace TutorialPoint { 
   export function add(x, y) { console.log(x + y);} 
}
```

Now when I saw the transpiled file which contains the js version of the same code, I did not understand anything in the file.

```
var TutorialPoint;
(
    function (TutorialPoint) {
        function add(x, y) {
            console.log(x + y);
        }
        TutorialPoint.add = add;
    }
)
    (TutorialPoint || (TutorialPoint = {}));
```

I am doing Js for some 3 months now. I don't understand why `function(TutorialPoint)` is inside parenthesis. I don't understand anything after the first variable declaration except the `console.log` part. What is the meaning of the last line `(TutorialPoint || (TutorialPoint={})).

Comment: _"I don't understand why `function(TutorialPoint)` is inside parenthesis"_... it's an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about not being able to follow transpiled code, especially as a beginner. It is not intended to be human readable.

Comment: Think of the result as `var TutorialPoint = { add: function(x, y) { console.log(x + y) } }`. This single example is quite contrived and given more complexity or multiple namespace additions, it makes sense to use an IIFE like this. And like @Charly said, for compiled code, you're only interested in the usable result. Readability is not a requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var TutorialPoint; // declare a varialble named TutorialPoint

// Define an IIFE, Immediately Invoking Function (I'll come to this later)
// This method takes an argument named TutorialPoint
(function (TutorialPoint) {
    // inside this IIFE, define a method add
    function add(x, y) {
      console.log(x + y);
    }
    // In the argument passed to the IIFE, the TuotiralPoint should be an object, so assign a new key add and point it to the add method defined above
    TutorialPoint.add = add;
 } // call the function with TutorialPoint variabled defined above, if above variables is undefined, then treat it as a {}
)(TutorialPoint || (TutorialPoint = {}));
```

Now, let's dive deep into understanding the code better.

1. What is an IIFE?

IIFE stands for Immediately Invoking Function Expression. In Javascript, you write functions as follows:

```js
function printName(firstname, lastname) {
  console.log(firstname, lastname);
}
```

Now, you can call the above function as follows

```js
printName("John", "Doe");
```

Or, you can also call the function immediately after defining it as follows

```js
(function printName(firstname, lastname) {
  console.log(firstname, lastname);
})("John", "Doe") // notice how we passed the parameters.
```

Now, let us understand the logic behind `TutorialPoint || (TutorialPoint = {}`;

Let us first understand the `a || b` expression

`||` is a Logical OR operator. The `||` operator in Javascript returns the value of one of the operands if one of the operands is Non-Boolean.

In simple words, If you do `const name = undefined || "John"`, you will get `John` as undefined is false when converted to `Boolean(undefined);`. So it returns `John`;

In your case `TutorialPoint` is undefined, so the second value of `{}` is being used. This means for the beginning, it is being assigned a value of `{}`;

In the expression, `TutorialPoint` is assigned a value of `{}` if it is undefined, which is the initial case when the function is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break it down. First, reformatting this to what makes more sense to me:

```js
var TutorialPoint;

(function (TutorialPoint) {
  function add(x, y) {
    console.log(x + y);
  }
  TutorialPoint.add = add;
})(TutorialPoint || (TutorialPoint = {}));
```

This snippet contains an anonymous function. This function receives an object as an argument, and adds a an `add` function to it. The function is called immediately.

Lets reformat it again to make this a bit more clear. Note that this is *not* an exact equivalent, and neither will the next snippets.

```js
var TutorialPoint;

// Define it first, and give it a name. This adds the 'add'
// function to an existing object.
function addAddToObject(obj) {

  function add(x, y) {
    console.log(x+y);
  }
  obj.add = add;

}

// Call it in a separate statement
addAddToObject(TutorialPoint || (TutorialPoint = {});
```

The weird argument passed to `addAddToObject` makes sure that either:

1. The `add` function is added to an already defined `TutorialPoint`, OR
2. TutorialPoint gets initialized as an empty object.

We can reformat that a bit more:

```js
var TutorialPoint;

function addAddToObject(obj) {

  // Lets simplify this too. Again this is not 100% equivalent
  obj.add = (x, y) => {
    console.log(x,y);
  }

}

if (!TutorialPoint) {
  // Initialize TutorialPoint if it didn't exist yet
  TutorialPoint = {};
}

addAddToObject(TutorialPoint);
```